# Is there a limit to combining characters with unicode?

Tags: unicode, combining-marks

I know there can be an arbitrary amount of characters, but is there a limit to how many you can add? And if there is a possible way to add a combining character onto a combining character that has been combined with a normal letter.

Comment: [No](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/17034).

Comment: [There is no limit in Unicode itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184958/).  What you are describing is commonly known as [Zalgo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zalgo) text. Also see [What is a realistic maximum number of unicode combining characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50272889/).

Comment: I think there are a soft limit but I do not find anymore the reference. IIRC, direct inputs could have much more characters, but text should have a limit of 32 or 64 codepoints per character. But yes. you can add the same combining character different times (and it will be displayed above the previous (if it was an accent). Check Normalization and Combining Classes.